# How to get all closest matched strings from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance, substring

I am trying to find closest match from an array.  For this I use `levenshtein()`, but `levenshtein()` returns only first matched string or first closest match.

Here is my scenario:

```
$words = array('Break Noise','Engine Noise','Vehicle is jerking');
```

If my input is `Noise`, I want to get both `Break Noise` and `Engine Noise`.

Is it possible to do?

`levenshtein()` returns me only `Break Noise` which is the first element.

Comment: Get the Levenshtein distance for each element, then sort the array by the distance.

Comment: What do you mean it returns only the closest match? `levenshtein()` returns a number that shows the distance between two strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After getting two upvotes, I'm sucked into leaving this answer on the screen.

```
$input="Noise";
$words = array('Break Noise','Engine Noise','Noises','Vehicle is jerking','Nose','noise');
$filtered=array_filter($words,function($v)use($input){return stripos($v,$input)!==false;});

usort($filtered,function($a,$b)use($input) {
    return levenshtein($input,$a)>levenshtein($input,$b)?1:-1;
});

var_export($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Noises',
  1 => 'noise',
  2 => 'Break Noise',
  3 => 'Engine Noise',
)
```

This will first filter out "Noise-less" elements, then sort your array using `levenshtein()`.

Comment: @mickmackusa, yeah my bad, sorry.

Comment: @mickmackusa, If my input string is a sentence like a "There is a break noise", so is it possible to get the same result. Or what changes should I do in code?

Comment: I have description field in which user can put any random description(sentences), so depends on the description, I want to suggest the diagnosis(which is nothing but the values in array ), so I want to find the closest value(s) from an array and show that value(s) to user.

Comment: @MK3007 Your latest extension is too far removed from this question, so I don't wish to deal with it on this page -- you should open up a new question.  HOWEVER, before you do, take some time to consider the data that you likely to encounter from users versus the dataset that you can construct.  I spent 10 minutes thinking about how I might do this.  Here are just 2 of the many, many ways you _could_ go (and these aren't very sharp):  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/517751f6dbda128fdedef39c30ab313428cf5b8f  You need to spend some time developing your design before asking for help.

Comment: ... if your users are going type a sentence, you might as well strip out all of the articles, conjunctions, pronouns, etc. that will useless as search terms.   The more I think about it, there will be hundreds of ways to skin this cat.  Good luck with this project.

Comment: @mickmackusa, Thanks for your guidance.